# VBA function to return all unique matching values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have been in search of an solution that would allow an Excel user to enter a formula, similar to a vlookup, that would return all unique matching values to a single cell.

I wrote the following code that seems to work, but I am trying to run the function in 2000+ cells and it runs pretty slow on my Thinkstation-S30 and I am afraid it will crash anyone trying to open the file from a slower machine.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to make the function more efficient?  I apologize for the sloppy code, i am an accountant by trade...

```
Public Function MvalLookup(Lookup_vector As Range, Result_vector As Range,_
Criteria As Variant, Seperator As String)
'
' Returns a list of all unique values matching the criteria
'

Dim arr As New Collection, a
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim result As String
Dim lookuprange As Integer

z = Lookup_vector.Rows.Count
j = 0
On Error Resume Next
For lookuprange = 1 To z
'determine how many values match- determine the required array size
If CStr(Lookup_vector(lookuprange, 1)) = CStr(Criteria) Then
    arr.Add CStr(Result_vector(lookuprange, 1)), CStr(Result_vector(lookuprange, 1))
    j = j + 1
End If
Next lookuprange

' Write results

result = arr(1)
If arr.Count <= 1 Then GoTo Output
For i = 2 To arr.Count
     result = result & Seperator & arr(i)
Next

Output:
'Output results
MvalLookup = result

End Function
```

Comment: How slow does this run? I am not sure the speed difference between using a collection and an array, but that may increase your speed.

Comment: You might want to read this post and the following 4 on writing fast and efficient UDFs: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-1/  https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/writing-efiicient-vba-udfs-part5-udf-array-formulas-go-faster/

Comment: It takes about 30-45sec to run on my PC with a 2.6ghz processor.  I will take a look at changing it to an array, thanks!

Comment: That is a good question for Code Review ! (https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You should change i, j, z into `Long`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link Ralph, the suggestions in that article really helped.  Just by storing the ranges as array's, took almost 10 seconds off the processing time!

Here is the revised code:

```
Public Function MvalLookup(Lookup_vector As Range, Result_vector As Range,_
Criteria As Variant, Seperator As String)
'
' MValLookup Macro
' Returns a list of all unique values matching the criteria
'

Dim arr As New Collection, a
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim result As String
Dim lookuprange As Integer
Dim LUVect As Variant
Dim RESVect As Variant

z = Lookup_vector.Rows.Count
j = 0
LUVect = Lookup_vector.Value2
RESVect = Result_vector.Value2
On Error Resume Next
For lookuprange = 1 To z
'determine how many values match- determine the required array size
If CStr(LUVect(lookuprange, 1)) = CStr(Criteria) Then
    arr.Add CStr(RESVect(lookuprange, 1)), CStr(RESVect(lookuprange, 1))
    j = j + 1
End If
Next lookuprange

' Write results

result = arr(1)
If arr.Count <= 1 Then GoTo Output
For i = 2 To arr.Count
     result = result & Seperator & arr(i)
Next

Output:
'Output results
MvalLookup = result

End Function
```